# Is there a console for Windows Mobile devices?

Tags: windows-mobile, console

I would like to write small console based applications on Windows Mobile.  What console applications might I use?

Answer (score 1):

it may be useful to know that when you use printf from a standard windows mobile application, the output will end up in the kernel log of the device.

This has several drawbacks:
 * Access to the kernellog is manufacturer+device dependent.
 * The length of the string you can print is limited to 255 characters.

if you run your tool in the visualstudio environment in the debugger, you will get the output of the printf's in your log window.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command prompt style console on Windows Mobile.  If you're really after a command prompt, check out www.pocketdos.com for a high level of dos application compatibility.
If you're more interested in writing small applications for Windows Mobile, C# or VB.Net are your best choices.
On small mobile devices like this, command prompts are significantly harder for users to interact with compared to GUI based applications.